# Typo3 foreign_table & foreign_table_where in TCA

Tags: typo3

I am struggling with the following problem.

I have two database tables, "Books" and "Category". I am getting all the data from "books"-table via Sysfolder in Backends List-view for editing, sorting and controlling them.

What I would like to get, is that there would be in that list view also the name of the category where the book belongs.

In "Books"-table there is a field foreign-key `"category_id"` which defines that for which category the Book belongs. I have tried via this `"category_id"` to get the name of the Category in List-view of the Books.

When I define in `TCA['books']` that `category_id` like:

```
'category_id' => array (        
            'exclude' => 0,     
            'label' => 'Cat name',      
            'config' => array (
                'type'     => 'select',
                'foreign_table' => 'category',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND category.id=###REC_FIELD_category_id###',
                'eval'     => 'int',
                'checkbox' => '0',
                'default' => 0
            )
        ),
```

it connects the Books and Categories using `category_id` (in Books-table) and `uid` (in Category-table).

Not like I would like, that it would connect them using category_id(in Books-table) and id(in Category-table). This id is a id of the category and can be different that uid.

Am I doing something wrong or does Typo3 somehow automatically makes this "connection" to foreign tables `uid`. ? Is there some way to get it like I would like?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it's not possible to specify different foreign key. So unless somebody proves me wrong, here is a workaround that I would use.

`itemsProcFunc` of the **[select](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.3.0/view/4/2/#id2522688)** type allows you to completely override the items in the menu and thus create a different relation.

1. Create an extra class that will be loaded in the backend only and that will have the method that will be called in the `itemsProcFunc`:

   `yourMethod($PA, $fobj)`
2. Make the method to load all the categories you want to have in the SELECT box and set them in the `$PA['items']` by completely overriding it so that it is an array of arrays where the 0 key is element title and 1 key is the category ID that you want. See `items` in **[select](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.3.0/view/4/2/#id2522688)**.

   `$PA['items'] = array(array($title, $id, ''));`
3. Include the class in the **ext_tables.php**:

   `if(TYPO3_MODE == 'BE') require_once(t3lib_extMgm::extPath($_EXTKEY).'class.YOUR_CLASS.php');`
4. Set the config for the category field in the books table:

   `'itemsProcFunc' => 'tx_YOUR_CLASS->yourMethod',`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it on that way.

So, I made a class file in folder typo3conf/ext/MY_EXTENSION.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it on that way.

So, I made a class file in folder typo3conf/ext/MY_EXTENSION.

In that file I made a class with a method.

I included the class in the ext_tables.php

And at the end I setted the itemsProcFunc in config for the category field to my method.

Did I understood something wrong now. I tried to get a response by making simple echo and exit in my method, but nothing happens when I load the List-view in Backend, it shows up like earlier.

Comment: If you are checking only with `echo`, make sure that you are really not getting the output. Note that the echo output might be hidden behind the form fields and that it won't be at the beginning of the HTML code and also make sure your are checking the right frame. It might be better to check by modifying the `$PA['items']` as in step 2. If you are really not getting anything, check that you haven't made any mistake - that the class is included and that you set `itemsProcFunc` to the right class and method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great answer of cascaval:
@cascaval: Do you mind pointing to the select.items in the Typo3TCA in the select links? The current links aren't straight forward.

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/singlehtml/#columns-select-properties-items

(no permission to comment to your answer, so had to answer myself just for this link ... weird)